# RegEx vs. Manually Parsing String (PHP Performance)

Tags: php, string

Is there any problem (performance-wise) with manually parsing a string as follows, as opposed to using Regular Expressions or the built in string replacement functions?

```
for ($i=0;$i<strlen($string);$i++) {
    $thisChar = $string[$i];
    //do more stuff
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: How are you using the above code?

Comment: For one, you could save the value of `strlen($string)` in a variable and pass that to the `for()` function. Right now, in every loop it's checking the length of `$string`.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger Yeah, this isn't real code, I just typed it up real quick right in the question's text box.

Comment: @summea I am searching for custom flags in a text document and the searches will change based on the first part of the string.  Each flag is encapsulated with a constant set of characters, but beyond that there are a lot of different possibilities that will trigger different responses in the parser.  If I do it as above, it means each character has to be read only once and (I assume) it should run much faster.  I'm not sure exactly how PHP handles its strings though, which is where my question comes in. :)

Comment: Idoubt you are grossly going to wreck performance, but here are some rules for guidance: 1. Unless your are a stundent, dont reinvent the wheel.  2. Unless you are adding functionality that is not already in the library, do not reinvent the wheel.. 3. If you cant analyze the efficiency ofyour own implementation of an algorithm, do not try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @skzryzg Understood, and on point number 3 I'd just like to point out that I am certainly capable of analyzing the implementation of an algorithm, I just wasn't sure if there were any issues specifically with how PHP handles string access.

Answer (score 0):

There are things that are done more efficient with custom code than with regex.

As long as both have the same O complexity and your not handling humongous strings, readability and maintainability should be an equally or even more important argument.

For the actual performance just do a benchmark to compare the two solutions.

Comment: By the way, the code you provided is not sufficient to give a clear answer.

Comment: I'm on a time crunch, and it's a relatively complex implementation that would take a bit of time to set up a benchmark for.  I just wanted to make sure that this approach wasn't itself inherently slow.